# Is this the best way to do this? Is there a cleaner way?

Tags: java, refactoring

This method is working as intended but I am wondering is there a better cleaner way to write it using modern Java elements.

```
    /**  
     * Counts how many strings in a given list are shorter than a given min length  
     * @param strings  
     * @param minLength  
     * @return  
     */  
    public int countShortStrings(List<String> strings, int minLength){  
        int numShort = 0;  
        for (String str : strings) {  
            if (str.length() < minLength) {  
                numShort++;  
            }  
        }  
        return numShort;  
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Ok @Someprogrammerdude. Thanks for making me aware. Should I close it? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s:

```
public long countShortStrings(List<String> strings, int minLength){  
    return strings.stream().filter(str -> str.length() < minLength).count();
}
```